# How to response a html file from external express Router file

Tags: node.js, express, router, express-router

How can i render from outside any html documents wit express.router().

My app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const https_port = 443;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
const homeRoute = require('./routes/home')
const userRoute = require('./routes/user')
app.use('/user', userRoute)
app.use('/home', homeRoute)


//Create server
https
  .createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync("ssl/privkey.pem"),
      cert: fs.readFileSync("ssl/cert.pem"),
    },
      app
  )
  .listen(https_port, () => {
    console.log('https server is running on port 443')
  });

  app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
```

my home.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router()

router.get("/", (req,res) => {
   // res.send("Home site")
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');
})

router.post("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send("Home site")
})

router.put("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send("Home site")
})

router.delete("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send("Home site")
})

module.exports = router;
```

The folder structure is:

```
public
   --> index.html
   --> login.html
routes
   --> home.js
   --> user.js
app.js
```

if i type in the browser `http://<MYADRESS>/home` i get this message in browser:
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/root/PWA/routes/login.html`

Which is also understandable, because the `login.html` file isn´t in the routes folder.  But how can i call the `login.html` file from my `home.js` router file?

i found the `redirect()` methode in the Express doc and with `...res.redirect('/login.html');...` it works.

But is this the right way?

Comment: Please clarify what result did you expect? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to route over my static html files like index.html , about.html, admin.html etc. With `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/login.html'));` its work fine. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const homeRoute = require('./routes/home');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
app.use('/home', homeRoute);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('https server is running on port 3000');
});
```

`routes/home.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/login.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

You can access the `index` page via:

- Static file: `http://localhost:3000/index.html`
- Route: `http://localhost:3000/`

Access the `login` page via:

- Static file: `http://localhost:3000/login.html`
- Route: `http://localhost:3000/home`